# Derivative using product rule and chain rule

Tags: calculus

I have no idea how to do this problem I am suppose to find the derivative of $y=\cos(a^3 + x^3)$ but I do not really know how to start this problem. At first I thought I could use the sum rule and just make it $3a^2$ and $3x^2$ but for some reason I do not think that is correct, possibly because I am solving for $x$ and for some rule I can not get the derivative of a like that.

Anyways what I tried was using the product rule which gave me $\cos(a^3 + x^3)\prime -\sin(a^3 + x^3)$ not sure if that makes sense but I attempted to get the derivative of $(a^3 + x^3)$ using the chain rule and I got completely  the wrong answer. I ended up with this abomination, $3\cos(a+x)^2  -\sin(a^3 + x^3)$

Comment: It is the Chain Rule. Let $u=a^3+x^3$. Then $y=\cos u$.  Note that since $a$ is assumed to be a constant, $\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2$. I think the rest of the Chain Rule has been explained to you. You should end up with $-3x^2\sin(a^3+x^3)$, or something equivalent to that.

Comment: This is just a relatively straightforward application of your previous question. I'd suggest looking at [Jonas' answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66724/the-chain-rule-how-to-interpret-it/66744#66744) again.

Comment: Is $a^3+x^3$ the same as $(a+x)^3$? to me it is when I put in numbers for a and x.

Comment: @Jordan: No, it's not the same. And it's not the same when you put in numbers, either. If $a=x=1$, then $a^3+x^3 = 1^3+1^3 = 1+1 = 2$; but $(a+x)^3 = (1+1)^3 = 2^3 = 8$. Is $2$ the same as $8$?

Comment: No it isn't. Almost any choice of $a$ and $x$ will show that. Take for example $a=1$, $x=2$.

Comment: I still can't get the correct answer, I am getting $-3sin(a^3+x^3)(3a^2 + 3x^2)$

Comment: @Jordan: Where did the first $3$ come from? And you are still treating $a^3$ as if $a$ were a variable. It's a *constant*, so its derivative is $0$.

Comment: Well I did 2 for a and x but I guess that is wrong because they are both 2, but it was something I could do in my head.

Comment: As a second point, I'm not a fan of Newtonian notation to indicate a derivative, e.g. $f'(x)$, and I prefer Leibniz's, e.g. $df/dx$, because it is difficult to tell which variable to use when calculating a derivative like, $\cos(a^3 + x^3)'$. In first semester calculus, this is easier as it is likely to be $x$. But, Leibniz's notation leaves less room for ambiguity, and that can be a life saver when doing these. However, professors insist on using Newton's form, so you have to learn it, also. But, I'd change it to the other form when working these.

Comment: What do you mean "you did 2 for a and x"? Again: $a$ is a constant, $a^3$ is just a constant, the derivative of a constant is $0$, no matter how you write it. The derivative of $\pi^8$ is $0$, not $8\pi^7$, because $\pi^8$ is... a constant. The derivative of $a^3$ is $0$, because $a^3$ is a constant.

Comment: The $a$ is supposed to be a constant, so $a^3$ is a constant, the derivative of a constant with respect to $x$ is $0$. By the way, it is dangerous to put the $3a^2+3x^2$ (which should be $3x^2$) at the end like you did, since it may look as if you are taking the sine of $[(a^3+x^3)(3x^2)]$.  Better is $(3x^2)(-\sin(a^3+x^3))$ or more simply $-3x^2\sin(a^3+x^3)$.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that a was a constant, I don't know how I overlooked that. I do that a lot when I am working with problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't write things like "$+-\sin(a^3+x^3)$"; they tend to confuse you later on. If you must put the addition and the negative sign, use parentheses, like $+(-\sin(a^3+x^3))$.

Next: $a$ is a constant; the variable is $x$. Constants have zero derivative. So you don't get $3a^2$ and $3x^2$.

Finally: the derivative of $y=\cos(a^3+x^3)$. This is a composition: if you write it as $f(g(x))$, then $g(x) = a^3+x^3$ (first you cube $x$ and add $a^3$ to it) and $f(u)=\cos u$ (then you take the cosine of whatever you have).

So $g'(x) = (a^3)' + (x^3)' = 0 + 3x^2 = 3x^2$ (again, $a$ is a constant).

On the other hand, $f'(u) = -\sin(u)$.

So, using the Chain Rule that says that
$$\Bigl( f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\Bigr)' = f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)g'(x),$$
we have
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\cos(a^3+x^3)\right)' &= \left(f'(a^3+x^3)\right)g'(x)\\
&= \left(-\sin(a^3+x^3)\right)\left(3x^2\right)\\
&= -3x^2\sin(a^3+x^3).
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

So is y the function of x: i.e. $y(x)$? or y is the function of both x and a: i.e. $y(x,a)$?

If y is only the function of x, then you just need to use the chain rule to de the derivative:

$dy = -\sin(a^3+x^3)\cdot 3x^2 dx$

If y is the function for both x and a, then you should use chain rule on both variables:

$dy = -\sin(a^3 + x^3)\cdot (3a^2 da + 3x^2 dx)$

Comment: Whether the function is of one variable or two depends on the context. It is a kind of convention that $x$ is a variable and $a$ is a constant, but your observation does point out to me that the question asks for the derivative, but does not specify what derivative is required. However, $x$ is stated to be variable and $a$ constant.