# Derivative of function raised to a power, using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I find the derivative of the function $f(x)= (2x+1)^2$? I've tried doing this problem and am not fully sure that I am correct. I found the derivative to be $f'(x) = 8x+4$. Is that correct?

Comment: could you write some of the steps you used and what you thought while doing so?Just as a guidance...the result is  correct.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, especially T.Bongers!

Comment: Amire, I used the chain rule as T. Bongers used it. I simply wanted to check if I was doing it right and I was. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks Sasha! I couldn't find the prime symbol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the derivative is correct.

---

To insert the details, note that $f(x) = (h \circ g)(x)$ with $$g(x) = 2x + 1$$ and $$h(u) = u^2$$ Then the chain rule simply says that

$$f'(x) = h'(g(x)) g'(x)$$

Now $h'(u) = 2u$ and so $h'(g(x)) = 2 g(x) = 2(2x + 1)$. On the other hand, $g'(x) = 2$; putting it together, we get

$$f'(x) = 2(2x + 1) 2 = 8x + 4$$

as you've stated.

Answer (score 0):

The Chain Rule: If $g$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$, then the composite function $F=f\circ g$
 defined by $F(x)=f(g(x))$ is differentiable at x and $F'$ is given by the product $$F'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).$$If $f(x)=(2x+1)^2$, then $f'(x)=2(2x+1)2=4(2x+1)=8x+4$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you apply the chain rule when you have an expression $f(g(x))$. In this case, $g(x) = (2x+1)$, and your $f(a) = a^2$. The chain rule says that $f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. Work out the derivatives: $g'(x) = 2$, $f'(x) = 2a$. Substitute $g'(x)$ for $a$ and put it all together: $2(2x+1)\cdot2 = 4(2x+1) = 8x+4$.

Also, this question is essentially a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66781/derivatives-using-chain-rule?rq=1). Please refrain from asking questions that have already been [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66724/the-chain-rule-how-to-interpret-it?rq=1) before.